# An identity related to $q$-series

Tags: number-theory, theta-functions, q-series

While studying Ramanujan's theta functions, I encountered a q-series $(q;q)_\infty^2\phi(q)$. I calculated the first few terms of $(q;q)_\infty^2\phi(q)$ and observed that it seems to have the following form:

$$(q;q)_\infty^2\phi(q)=\sum_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n\geq1}{n\ \text{odd}}}\left(\frac n3\right)nq^{(n^2-1)/12},\tag1$$

where $(q;q)_\infty=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)$ and $\phi(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}$. I have attempted to find a reference for this series but have not made any progress.

**My question is:** How to prove (1)?

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah. But there is no corresponding list in the OEIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevin Zheng says in his answer, you can use the Jacobi triple product identity on $\phi(q)$.  Then, substituting $s=e^{2\pi i z}=q^2$ reduces the identity (1) to
$$s^{-1/24}\frac{\eta(z)^5}{\eta(2z)^2}=\frac{(s;s)_\infty^5}{(s^2;s^2)_\infty^2}=\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-s^n)^3 (1-s^{2n-1})^2 = 
\sum_{ \text{odd}\ n\geq1}\left(\frac n3\right)ns^{(n^2-1)/24}.\qquad (2)$$
This follows from the quintuple product identity
$$
\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-s^n)(1-s^nt)(1-s^{n-1}t^{-1})(1-s^{2n-1}t^2)(1-s^{2n-1}t^{-2}) 
= \sum_{n}s^{(3n^2+n)/2}(t^{3n}-t^{-3n-1})
$$
if you divide both sides by $1-t^{-1}$, expand the quotient $(t^{3n}-t^{-3n-1})/(1-t^{-1})$, and then set $t$ equal to 1.  This proof of (2) was given by Basil Gordon in 1961 [[1](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/12.1.285)].  (2) was earlier found by Ramanujan [[3](https://books.google.com/books?id=_wvuY4DoIdYC)].  Also, (2) is identity (8.19) in Theorem 8.5 in [[2](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-16152-0)], and there is some more discussion of the history of it there.

[1](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/12.1.285): "Some Identities in Combinatorial Analysis", B. Gordon, *The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics*,  **12**, #1 (1961), pp. 285-290.

[2](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-16152-0): *Eta Products and Theta Series Identities*, Günter Köhler, Springer, 2011.

[3](https://books.google.com/books?id=_wvuY4DoIdYC): "On certain arithmetical functions", *Transactions of the Cambridge Philosophical Society* **22** (1916), pp. 159-184, at p. 170.

Answer (score 2):

I found an identity in the last one of Theorem 1.1 of [1], say

$$\frac{\eta^5(24z)}{\eta^2(48z)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n}{12}\right)nq^{n^2}.$$

Moreover, we have

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}=\frac{(q^2;q^2)_\infty^5}{(q;q)_\infty^2(q^4;q^4)_\infty^2},$$

by Jacobi's Triple Product Identity. Thus, the desired result come from if we substitude $q$ by $q^{12}$ of (1) and then multiply the both sides of (1) with $q$.

[1] *Lemke Oliver, Robert J.*, [**Eta-quotients and theta functions**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2013.03.019), Adv. Math. 241, 1-17 (2013). [ZBL1282.11030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1282.11030).