# Ramanujan's identity concerning a quotient of Dedekind's eta functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, theta-functions, q-series

In his paper [*On certain Arithmetical Functions*](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram18.html) (published in *Transactions of the Cambridge Philosophical Society*, XXII, No. 9, 1916, pp. 159-184) Ramanujan  presents the following identities (as if they are quite well known and rather obvious)
\begin{align} 
f(q) &= q^{1^2/24}-q^{5^2/24}-q^{7^2/24}+q^{11^2/24}+\dots\tag{1}\\
f^3(q)&=q^{1^2/8}-3q^{3^2/8}+5q^{5^2/8}-7q^{7^2/8}+\dots\tag{2}\\
\frac{f^5(q)}{f^2(q^2)}&=q^{1^2/24}-5q^{5^2/24}+7q^{7^2/24}-11q^{11^2/24}+\dots\tag{3}\\
\frac{f^5(q^2)}{f^2(-q)}&=q^{1^2/3}-2q^{2^2/3}+4q^{4^2/3}-5q^{5^2/3}+\dots\tag{4}
\end{align}
where $$f(q) =q^{1/24}(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)\dots\tag{5}$$ and $1,2,4,5, \dots$ are the natural numbers without the multiples of $3$ and $1,5,7,11,\dots$ are the natural odd numbers without the multiples of $3$.

The function $f(q) $ is Dedekind's eta function and due to the presence of 24th root the symbol $f(-q) $ is confusing. What is really meant by $f(-q) $ is the expression $$q^{1/24}(1-(-q))(1-(-q)^2)(1-(-q)^3)\dots$$ so that we change the sign of $q$ in factors other than $q^{1/24}$.

The formulas $(1),(2)$ are really well known as Euler's pentagonal theorem and Jacobi identity respectively and both of these can be derived using the Jacobi triple product identity $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1}z)(1+q^{2n-1}z^{-1})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^nq^{n^2}\tag{6}$$

Formula $(3)$ was recently discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4774881/) and a proof based on Quintuple product identity is given in one of the answers.

The formula $(4)$ is the one which is left to prove and the similarity of its left hand side with that of $(3)$ indicates that it may be amenable to Quintuple product identity as well. However I have been unable to establish it so far using Quintuple product identity.

The identity is given in the form $$\frac{(\eta(3z)\eta(12z))^2}{\eta(6z)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{3}\right) nq^{n^2}\tag{7}$$ (where $q=\exp(2\pi i z) $ and $\eta(z) =f(q)$) as a part of a larger set of identities in the paper [*Eta-quotients and theta functions*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2013.03.019) by Robert J. Lemke Oliver and it is established using the theory of modular forms.

I am searching for a proof which avoids modular forms and is of a more elementary character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, (4) can be proved from the quintuple product identity
$$
\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-s^n)(1-s^nt)(1-s^{n-1}t^{-1})(1-s^{2n-1}t^2)(1-s^{2n-1}t^{-2}) 
= \sum_{n}s^{(3n^2+n)/2}(t^{3n}-t^{-3n-1}).
$$
This can be done as follows: set $s:=q^2$ and $t:=q^{-1}y$; then you get
\begin{eqnarray*}
&\ &\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1}y)(1-q^{2n-1}y^{-1})(1-q^{4n-4}y^2)(1-q^{4n}y^{-2})\\ 
&=&\sum_{n}q^{3n^2-2n} y^{3n} - q^{3n^2+4n+1} y^{-3n-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
so, shifting the index $n$ in two places,
\begin{eqnarray*}
&(1-y^2)&\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1}y)(1-q^{2n-1}y^{-1})(1-q^{4n}y^2)(1-q^{4n}y^{-2})\\ 
&=&\sum_{n}q^{3n^2-2n} (y^{3n} - y^{-(3n-2)}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Divide both sides by $1-y^2$ and then set $y:=1$; this gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n\ge 1} (1-q^{2n})(1-q^{2n-1})^2(1-q^{4n})^2
&=&-\sum_{n} (3n-1)q^{3n^2-2n}\\
&=&\sum_n (3n+1)q^{3n^2+2n}\\
&=&\sum_{n\ge 1} (\frac n 3) n q^{(n^2-1)/3},
\end{eqnarray*}
which becomes (4) after multiplying by $q^{1/3}$ and rewriting the left-hand side.  This proof is more or less the same as the one given by Basil Gordon in 1961 [[1](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/12.1.285)].

[1](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/12.1.285): (12) in "Some Identities in Combinatorial Analysis", B. Gordon, *The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics*,  **12**, #1 (1961), pp. 285-290.